# How do I convert a relative path in Ant to an absolute path?

Tags: ant

I would like to convert a relative path to an absolute path.

How is that done?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The location attribute on the [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) will convert relative paths to absolute.

```
<property name="absolute.path" location="${relative.path}"/>
```