# Ant script failing with error "source file does not exist" despite the file exists,

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, ant

below is the script I am using and it is failing with error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Source File: ../CalcMgr/exploded/ear/adf/META-INF/adf-config.xml does not exist.
```

I tried running it locally and the `build.xml` works. But in jenkins server though the file exists it is failing with that error.

```
    <echo message="Replacing '#\{JAVASCRIPT_VERSION\}' with '${env.JAVASCRIPT_VERSION}' in file: '${exploded}/ear/adf/META-INF/adf-config.xml'" />
        <refactorbuildno fileName="${exploded}/ear/adf/META-INF/adf-config.xml" searchText="#\{JAVASCRIPT_VERSION\}" replaceText="${env.JAVASCRIPT_VERSION}"/>
```

Anyone kindly help to fix this

Comment: Did you check the character case of the path? Paths in Windows are case insensitve whereas paths under linux are case sensitive...

You also checked the output of the "echo" message?

Comment: I am building in windows both in local and in jenkins

Comment: please also try to print out the absolute path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136849/how-do-i-convert-a-relative-path-in-ant-to-an-absolute-path

Comment: I didn't understood what it means. I am not using any relative paths in my script. Can you please put it in the command what you exactly want me to add

Comment: FYI - ../CalcMgr/exploded/ear/adf/META-INF/adf-config.xml this path exists

Comment: Well, `../CalcMgr/...` is a relative path. Just try `<property name="absolute.path" location="${exploded}/ear/adf/META-INF/adf-config.xml"/><echo message="${absolute.path}" />` and check if the resulting path exists...

Comment: Thank You :) I will check and let you know

Comment: I am getting patha as [echo] C:\Jenkins\jobs\calcmanager\branches\mydevelop\workspace\calcBuild\${exploded}\ear\adf\META-INF\adf-config.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195662/discussion-between-sirfartalot-and-jon).

Comment: but what I want is      [echo] C:\Jenkins\jobs\calcmanager\branches\mydevelop\workspace\calcMgr\exploded\ear\adf\META-INF\adf-config.xml